# how to define a global function that has an event parameter in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Assume that I have the following function:

```
function onTilt( event )
    physics.setGravity( (-9.8*event.yGravity), (-9.8*event.xGravity) ) --Το σωστό
end
```

which will be used in many different lua files. I want to define it in an external file and then use require to this file so I will not repeat it in each lua file.

The problem is that this function is called like that when it is in the same file with the following (without passing an argument)

```
Runtime:addEventListener( "accelerometer", onTilt )
```

Can someone explain me how to define it in an external file and how to call then?

Comment: This helped me heaps http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b12YEOIry60 but now I've moved on to sprite kit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this minimal external module layout:

```
-- external module - file named "mymodule.lua"
local M = {}

function M.onTilt( event )
    physics.setGravity( (-9.8*event.yGravity), (-9.8*event.xGravity) )
end

return M
```

Where you need to use that function you can write (assuming `mymodule.lua` is put in a directory on your Lua search path):

```
local mymodule = require 'mymodule'    

-- ... other code ...

Runtime:addEventListener( "accelerometer", mymodule.onTilt )
```

Comment: can you give an example where the function has also another parameter, let's say `M.onTilt( event, level )` and I want to call it call it like `Runtime:addEventListener( "accelerometer", mymodule.onTilt(level) )` without passing the event parameter, only the level? thank you in advance

Comment: @AvraamMavridis, use a closure.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. As it is defined now, `onTilt` only parameter is `event`, so how a `level` argument should be used? What do you really want to execute when your listener is triggered?